# Maximization problem on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Consider a graph $G(V,E)$. Let degree of each vertex be denoted to $\beta(v) < d$. Maximize the following, where $\beta(v)$ is the only variable for all vertex $v\in V$.
$$
\max \sum_{(u,v)\in E} \big((d - \beta(u))*(d-\beta(v)\big)\\
s.t\\
\qquad\\
\sum_{v\in V}\beta(v) = (|V|-W)d\\
\sum_{v\in V}(d-\beta(v))*\beta(v) = |V|W
$$
Feel free to post answers with certain assumptions and 
**any** help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am mainly looking for an answer upto a constant. By which I mean that numerical constants can be ignored